# Network panel not working in weinre

Tags: ajax, mobile, weinre

I wanted to write an AJAX based hybrid Android application.
I tried to get my head around weinre but I can't get the network panel to appear. It does not show regular network interactions and for any XHR interaction it states "status pending" and "type pending".
Has anybody else faced this problem?.

This link did/did not solve the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5424

Comment: It would be great if you provide us some links or code listings.

Answer (score 1):

Weinre is pretty limited, and nowadays better solutions exist to inspect your Hybrid app:

- On Android 4.4 and above (or lower Android if you're using CrossWalk), you can use Chrome  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging Just point to chrome://inspect/#devices and you should see your device and hybrid apps and browsers. You may need to first run `adb start-server` for Chrome to see your device
- On iOS, you can use Safari (on a Mac): you need to enable *Web Inspector* on Safari on iOS, and use the *Developper* mode of Safari on the Mac. See eg http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/